# Context.startForgroundService() did not then call Service.Forground

Tags: java, android, service

I have called Context.startForgroundService() if device os is Android 9(Pie) but sometime it throw error like "**Context.startForgroundService() did not then call Service.Forground**", I have also give permission for forground sevice **android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE** still issue is not resolved.

```
if (!isMyServiceRunning(Service.class)){
            startService();
        }

private void startService() {
        System.out.println("Start Service");
        Thread t = new Thread("StartService") {
            public void run() {
                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.demo.demo.start_service");
                serviceIntent.setPackage("com.demo.demo");
                try {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(serviceIntent);

                    } else {
                        getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Answer (score 0):

the problem with foreground service is that it should start within 5 seconds or else you will find this error.. Now I have shared you this method, which I use it on my service class ONCREATE method. I hope you find this useful.

```
void CheckOSversion()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
            String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_01";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Channel human readable title",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).createNotificationChannel(channel);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle("")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .build();

            startForeground(002, notification);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Android Oreo 8.0 Documentation properly somewhere in here, you might not have posted this question here.

Step 1: Make sure you start a service as a foreground Service as given in below code

ContextCompat.startForegroundService(mainActivity, new Intent(getContext(), 
GpsServices.class));
 ContextCompat.startForegroundService(mainActivity, new Intent(getContext(), 
BluetoothService.class));
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(mainActivity, new Intent(getContext(), 
BackgroundApiService.class));
Step 2: Use notification to show that your service is running. Add below line of code 
in onCreate method of Service.

@Override
public void onCreate() {
...
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
}
...
}
Step 3: Remove the notification when the service is stopped or destroyed.

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
...
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      stopForeground(true); //true will remove notification
}
...
}
```